# Why I have to write " " before and after my app name to find it in google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I want to understand why I have to write quotes before and after my app name to find it in google play because if I wrote the name of my application without it, it never appear.
Google show me another apps that doesn't have my app name.
I only can find my app if I write the name like I have my apk name.

For example.
application name --> Where is Tom? 
if I write it like this google play show me all other apps where the name is not the same.
if you write whereistom(like apk name) my application is shown and if I write "where is tom" is shown too.

why? if there is no other app with the same name why never appear?

I did something wrong when I published it? Can I do something to finding it without quotes?

Thanks (sorry for my english)

Comment: It does not happen to me and i hear this from you first time, very strange. Your app on google play is named Where Is Tom but when you wrote Where Is Tom to google play, you can not find your app ha?

Comment: No if I write the name of my app without quotes appear all other apps that I don't want. If I wrote it between quotes appear in the first position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did nothing wrong I guess. When have you uploaded your apk and published the app? It may take some time (a couple of hours or even more) until your app will be found in the search results.

Beside that it depends on Googles searching heuristics what you'll get as a result:

> Search uses powerful heuristics to suggest terms as the user types, and it offers direct links to apps as suggestions. In results, users find the most relevant, most popular apps at the top.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/about/visibility.html

If you're using a very common name or some common words in the name your app may simply not be as relevant as other apps. Just guessing, no offense. ;)

Comment: I published it last week. I possible that in the first 10 or 20 positions the name was similar to my app name but then appear all other apps that the name is not similar.